# Adding Vectors in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, vector, 2d, addition

I need a solution to my problem which is adding vectors in java. I have been stuck for a while so any help will be greatly appreciated. Firstly, i have code to set and get x,y,z vectors that pre-exist.

```
class Vector{
  constructor(pX, pY, pZ){

this.setX(pX);

 this.setY(pY);

 this.setZ(pZ);

 }
 getX(){

     return this.mX;

}
setX(pX){

   this.mX = pX;

 } getY(){
        return this.mY;

 } setY(pY){

     this.mY = pY;

 } getZ(){

       return this.mZ;

 }setZ(pZ){
        this.mZ = pZ;
    }
```

The part I need help with is the addition which needs to meet a specific part of a specification. Below is the spec.

```
describe("Add", function () {
    var vector, secondVector, thirdVector;    
    vector = new Vector(30, 40, 0)       
    secondVector = new Vector(20, 30, 0);       
    thirdVector = vector.add(secondVector);
    it("X Set", function () {
        expect(thirdVector.getX()).toEqual(50);
    });
    it("Y Set", function () {
        expect(thirdVector.getY()).toEqual(70);
    });
});
```

Please can anybody give me a solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This strongly feels like a homework dump as you show no own efforts whatsoever although the problem only involves extremely basic concepts. Please tell me that I am wrong and show what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried multiple things but still cannot get to work. I didn't wish to show my addition attempt as this is a basic thing that i cannot get correct so i am embarrassed by it. However, I'm desperate for help so here is my latest attempt at it which feels very incorrect to me.                               
add(pVector){
        var x,y,z;
       
        x = this.getX();
        y = new Vector(20,30,0);

        z = this.add(pVector);

        return this;
    }

Comment: The thing is that you can convince other people of your good intentions by showing your attempts, no matter how silly they might seem to you. There is a huge number of people who just dump their homework here and expect others to do them for them. You want to make sure that you are not perceived as one of these people. Try `add(pVector) { return new Vector(this.getX() + pVector.getX(), this.getY() + pVector.getY(), this.getZ() + pVector.getZ()); }`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Nico, that solved my problem.